# Encoding PHP PDO MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, pdo

I am starting learn PDO with MS SQL Server.
Connecting with this code:

```
$userDB = 'userBD';
$passwordDB = 'passwordDB';

try {
  $DBH = new PDO('mssql:dbname=spr_bank;host=hostname', $userDB, $passwordDB);
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "<h1 style='font-weight:bold; color:red;'>Error. Can not connect to Database</h1>";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.log', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
}
```

and now, I select data from table:

```
      //simple query and binding with results
      $query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT name FROM spr_sotrudnik WHERE login = :login AND password = :password");

      $login = (isset($_POST['login']) === true) ? $_POST['login'] : '' ; // ? : shorthand for if else
      $password = (isset($_POST['password']) === true) ? md5($_POST['password']) : '' ; // ? : shorthand for if else

      // bind parameters - avoids SQL injection
      $query->bindValue(':login', $login);
      $query->bindValue(':password', $password);

      //try... if not catch exception
      try {
          // run the query
          $query->execute();

          while($rows = $query->fetch()){
            echo $rows["name"];
          }
      }
      catch(PDOException $e){
          echo $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine();
      }
```

When I go to the browser, I get this error:

> **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10007 Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. [10007] (severity 5) [(null)]D:\www\sklad_new\inc\auth.php19**

When I write this query 
`$query = $DBH->prepare(" SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),name) AS s FROM spr_sotrudnik WHERE login = :login AND password = :password");`

I have no error, but I see "**?????**"

How can I change this?

Comment: What [driver](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) are you using? PDO_DBLIB, PDO_ODBC or PDO_SQLSRV?

Comment: i think this [driver](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) , but I am not sure. How can I check it?

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't need to ask since you already show the DNS: `mssql:...`. You are using [PDO_DBLIB](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php).

Comment: *Oops... I meant* DSN, *not* DNS...

Comment: VARCHAR is NOT unicode, it is ASCII. I'll bet `name` is a NVARCHAR field and you are forcing it to ASCII using a codepage that is incompatible with the stored data. The default codepage matches the database's collation. You can use a specific collation using the COLLATE clause, but the real solution is to use a driver that supports Unicode

Answer (score 2):

You're omitting the `charset` parameter in the [DSN string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php):

```
$DBH = new PDO('mssql:dbname=spr_bank;host=hostname', $userDB, $passwordDB);
```

... so you're probably using default encodings along the whole toolchain.

In any case, the `PDO_DBLIB` driver is clearly [tagged as experimental](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) and includes this notice:

> On Windows, you should use SqlSrv, an alternative driver for MS SQL is
> available from Microsoft: »
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx .
>
> If it is not possible to use SqlSrv, you can use the [PDO_ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) driver
> to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases, as **the native
> Windows DB-LIB is ancient, thread un-safe and no longer supported by
> Microsoft**.

In my experience, this means that you can obtain all sort of unpredicted side effects.

Comment: @Mr.AbduJan - What the PHP manual suggests. I've edited the answer to include the full cite. But I suggest you find out what encoding is used by your app and your database; you'll need that info no matter the driver.